# if confirm ignores location.href

Tags: javascript, confirm

The following code reloads the page rather than the desired URL

```
    function delFile(name,id) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to DELETE '+name+'?')) {
        location.href='/cgi-bin/cnc.cgi?phrsrg~038919718485478~'+id ;
        alert('/cgi-bin/cnc.cgi?phrsrg~038919718485478~'+id);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In the alert, the id is shown as being added properly and the URL is correct. I can copy it from the alert, then use that text to get the right result. Other scripts on the same page that use similar location.href are working perfectly but this is the only one using confirm.

I've also tried

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

But the page still reloads.

The triggering link is:

```
onClick="return delFile('Bill','1234')
```

Comment: Try showing a [mcve]. You've provided bits of your code, but not the whole link.

Comment: have you try using window.open('http://stackoverflow.com','_parent');

Comment: opening curly braces is missing just after `delFile` signature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The href on the triggering link is still being linked to, because `delFile()` only returns false if the `confirm` is not accepted -- that's what's causing the page reload.  When the function returns true, the link fires before the redirect occurs.

You want the function to return false in all cases, so don't put the return in an `else` clause.

```js
function delFile(name, id) {
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to DELETE ' + name + '?')) {
    location.href = '/cgi-bin/cnc.cgi?phrsrg~038919718485478~' + id;
    alert('/cgi-bin/cnc.cgi?phrsrg~038919718485478~' + id);
  }
  return false; // always, since you always want to prevent the link's default behavior.  (Could also use event.preventDefault here.)
}
```

```html
<a href="/" onClick="return delFile('Bill','1234')">test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the delFile() function is missing the opening curly brace, so I would start by fixing that. If the issue persists, check the JS console. Also, posting a codepen would be helpful.

Comment: I was hoping you had found it but unfortunately it was a faulty copy and paste. The brace does exist in the script and has been added via edit to my query. Thanks

Comment: Check the JS console for errors and / or try adding some breakpoints. You want to narrow this down to what step it's failing on and why.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function delFile(name,id){
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to DELETE '+name+'?')) {
   /* var fullpath = better to use the full url name/link;*/
    var url = '/cgi-bin/cnc.cgi?phrsrg~038919718485478~'+id;
    window.open(url, '_parent');
        alert('/cgi-bin/cnc.cgi?phrsrg~038919718485478~'+id);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    }
```